# Angular 7 - How to make consequent http requests

Tags: angular, httprequest

I read lots of threads about this topic, but I've not understood hot to make it yet.

What I need is to  make one http request to our API, get the result, with this result I need to set some variables that are used in html. After all these operations are completed, I need to make a second http request and do the same thing (set variables used in html) and then a third http request and so on.

I read that concatMap is good for this, but it's not clear how to write the correct code in order to get the result of first code and do some stuff, and at the end of this, do the second call and so on...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you at least tried using it? If not, then try. If yes, what have you tried (post the code), and what difficulty did you face (give an explanation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) for that, here's an example:

```
   this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
      mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these APIs dependent? I mean are you using output of first API for making second API call?

If **no** you can make API calls parallel using `forkJoin`

If **yes** and APIs are more than two, i would suggest to use `toPromise()` and call then using `await`

```
const firstAPIOutput = await http.get('/api/person/1').toPromise();
//do some stuff with firstAPIOutput
const secondAPIOutput = await http.get('/api/person/2').toPromise();
//do some stuff with secondAPIOutput
//and so on
```

Comment: Ashish, not convert to Promise, use switchMap Rxjs (well, you can use mergeMap, for see the difference check, e.g. this link: https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885). It's more "natural way"

Comment: I know we should not mix rxjs with promises like this. But first of all such sort of requests should be handled in backend. Second thing the code for making 5 6 sequential requests using switchMap or mergeMap will be very difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to explain better what i need. I want to populate a web page with the result of an http request. This request generate a json that I use in my component to populate some variables in html. Json was very big so I decided to do 2 http calls. The first one generates a json with main data (I mean every data that is in "above the fold" of the web page), the second call generates a json with secondary content ((I mean every data that IS NOT in "above the fold" of the web page)). Now I'm doing it this way: I do first call (this.http.get('url1').subscribe(...). in the result I populate some variables and then I do (this.http.get('url2').subscribe(...). in the result of this second call I populate some other variables. The result of this is that my page first display data in "above the fold" part and then in the other parts. I read that doing a subscribe inside another subscribe is not the right way. I think that concatMap is of for having htt requests done consequently. But the real problem isho to get the result of every call and use it befor doing the following call.